# Copy SQL Server DB into another instance without SA access

Tags: sql-server

I've two SQL Server databases and both of them are on cloud.

1. First server is source
2. Second server is destination

I only have a non SA access. And I'm using DBForge Studio for managing the database. I'm trying to copy the database from the first server to the second server through `DBForge→Database Sync→Copy Database` and then select copy (I'm following this [article](https://codingsight.com/how-to-copy-sql-server-databases-from-one-instance-to-another/)).

Note:
The database already exists in destination with same name, but no tables yet.

I got an error message when trying to copy:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_fileexist'.....

Then I try to copy & overide but I got the same error message.

So I try to use another way like export & import. I export the database from source server into **.sql**, but there are only queries for insert, it didn't serve the query for create table schema, and I tried to import into another file like **.csv** and **.xsl** but I got the same, it only contain data without schema.

Is there any better way to copy the database without SA access?

Comment: What access do you have on the destination database?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any better way to copy the database without SA access?

Yes, you do not have to be `sa` or `sysadmin` member to perform the activity that you described, but following are the least privileges required to do so.:

**You must be member of**

1. Database role: `db_ddladmin` or Database role: `db_owner` at source server
2. Server role: `dbcreator` at destination server

You can verify current membership with following query (1=YES, 0=NO):

```
---- Source server
select  IS_MEMBER ('db_ddladmin' ) as Is_DDLAdmin, 
        IS_MEMBER ('db_owner' ) as Is_DBOwner
go

---- Destination server
select  IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('dbcreator' ) as Is_DBCreator
go
```

I haven't used **dbForge** studio, but using [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) free tool provided by Microsoft, and while having permissions (as mentioned above), you can achieve what your looking for (export data along with objects into `.sql` format)

via  SSMS -> Tasks -> [Generate script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-and-publish-scripts-wizard?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(sql13.swb.generatescriptswizard.saveorpublishscripts.f1)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-2017) option. focus on following options at [Advanced scripting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/media/generate-and-publish-scripts-wizard/advanced.png?view=sql-server-2017)

- Types of data to script = Data and schema
- Script for server version = your desired version

Comment: in source and destination I've same user role, which can only add, delete, modify record, column, and table. Base on your desc it should work. I'll try, thankyou